# Transforming async fetch results for async react-select control

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-select

I am trying to transform the return values from an async fetch call and return them to an async react-select component. It will populate the select component (with "blank" entries since they aren't in the right format) if I just pass in the fetch result but if I try to transform the fetch result to a {label: X, value: Y} format, the react select component shows no values in the drop down.

Option population function

```
  const promiseOptions = inputValue =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(
        fetch("/api/Client")
          .then(resp => resp.json())
          .then(function(data) { //not working if I transform data here
            data.map(x => {
              return {
                value: x.id,
                label: x.name
              };
            });
          })
      );
    });
```

React select async component

```
<AsyncSelect cacheOptions defaultOptions loadOptions={promiseOptions} />
```

Comment: Please provide more code, and you should use setState on fetch response

Answer (score 0):

for this instance you should use setState on fetch response and then for transforming data into value label you should handle it on loadOption with another method or function;
fetch is an Async method in nature and useing Promise is needless